# Why does this only return one 7?

Tags: java, arrays

I want this to replace all three integer of value 8 into 7. But the output only give me one seven...

```
public class hore {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = {8, 9, 8, 6, 9, 8};
        int number = count(list, 8, 7);
        System.out.print(number);
    }


    public static int count(int[] list, int target, int replacement) {
        for (int n : list) {
            if (n == target) {
                n = replacement;
            }
        }

        return replacement;
    } 

}
```

Comment: What do you expect to be printed? In your version of the code you just print the replacement number.

Comment: I want to print each replaced number

7, 7, 7

Answer (score 4):

When doing

```
n = replacement;
```

you're just changing the value of the local variable `n`, not the value in the list.

And you're not counting the values you change.

You can do this :

```
 int nbChanges = 0;
 for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i]==target) {
            list[i] = replacement;
            nbChanges++;
        }
 }
 return nbChanges;
```

Comment: @Sing Sandibar When you say "get" what do you mean? If this code is implemented correctly you should have an `int[]` array (called list), and you should print 3 (the number of replacements that took place)

Comment: Hi. It worked now. Maybe I did something wrong earlier. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you are returning the variable `replacement` which has value `7`.

You can get count of number of `8's` using this code:-

```
public static int count(int[] list, int target, int replacement) {

   int count = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < list.length; list++) {
      if (list[i] == target) {    
          count++;   
          list[i] = replacement;
      } 
   }
   return count;    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement at the end of your `count` function is

```
return replacement;
```

Which is the 3rd argument that you pass in here:

```
 int number = count(list, 8, 7);
```

Since the `count` function does not change the value of `replacement`, the value of `number` will be 7

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the Collections framework and use the [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#replaceAll%28java.util.List,%20T,%20T%29) function. You would have to use a list rather than an array though.

The replaceAll method has a similar signature to you count method.

It's always better to use the API if you can as this will be tried and tested.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are only changing the value of the local variable,
you need to change that in the array you are passing.

You can do ::

```
 for (int n=0;n<list.length();n++) 
 {
    if (list[n] == target) 
    {
       list[n] = replacement;
    }
 }
```